# why does make not expand stem in dependency when there is no action to take?

Tags: makefile

I have the following simplified Makefile:

```
foo-%: dep-%
        @echo in foo $*

bar-%: dep-%

dep-%:
        @echo in dep $*
```

`make dep-aa` works. What is interesting is that while `make foo-aa` works, `make bar-aa` does not, even though it has the same dependency on `dep-%`. Why is that? And how do you work around it?

```
$ make dep-aa
in dep aa
$ make foo-aa
in dep aa
in foo aa
$ make bar-aa
make: *** No rule to make target `bar-aa'.  Stop.
```

Obviously the simple case above does not add much, but if I have multiple sub-targets, it would be useful, e.g.

```
foo-%: abc-% def-% xyz-%
```

I figure I can do this somehow with static targets, not sure, but I would like to understand why the above does not work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) is pretty clear:

> You can cancel a built-in implicit rule by defining a pattern rule with the same target and prerequisites, but no recipe. For example, the following would cancel the rule that runs the assembler:
>
> ```
> %.o : %.s
> ```

Comment: Huh, I wasn't thinking like that. So if I want to do that, I need to have some noop recipe there?

Comment: Yes, if you want this to declare a prerequisite relationship you need a recipe.  Just adding a `;` at the end of the recipe line is sufficient: `%.o : %.s ;`